# Paste 2D images in an arbitrary orientation into a 3D volume

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, itk

I'm reading a series of 2D images with a specific location and orientation in space and put them into a 3D volume (itkImage with 3 dimensions). I'm using ITK for that and so far it works but it's rather slow.

Below is my code where img_data is a 2D image (itkImage) which is the source and vol_img is a 3D volume which is the destination. Both have an origin and an direction.

```
for i in range(0, width):
    for j in range(0, height):
        pixel_val = img_data.GetPixel(0, i, j)
        phys_point = img_data.TransformIndexToPhysicalPoint((0, i, j))
        img_point_vol = vol_img.TransformPhysicalPointToIndex(phys_point)

        vol_img.SetPixel(img_point_vol[0], img_point_vol[1], img_point_vol[2], pixel_val)
```

This method produces a 3D volume but is pretty slow. I also had a look to the sitk.Paste method but it doesn't allow to paste the image in an arbitrary orientation. I'm using python with SimpleITK

Is there a more efficient method for doing this than iterating over all pixels in the source image?

Comment: Seems like a NumPy array would work well, hard to tell if it's compatible with the functions you're using without knowing exactly what they're doing.

Comment: The functions I'm using just apply transformations from the coordinate system of the 2D image into the coordinate system of the 3D image, which I could easily implement for NumPy.

Is there an efficient way with NumPy arrays to achieve this? I guess if I have to iterate it will be inefficient again.

Comment: It would depend on how different the co-ordinate systems are, I think. Without knowing what the inside of `GetPixel`, and the two `Transform` looks like, it's really hard to know. If it's just a linear transform, then NumPy should deal with that ok.

Comment: GetPixel just gets the pixel value at the given position. The transformations consist of translation, rotation and scaling. The question is whether there is a way of inserting the data without iterating over all pixels.

Comment: If the translation, rotation and scaling are identical for every point, you should be able to adjust the Transforms to take a 3D array instead of individual points (or even 1D slices if the different dimensions have different transforms)